# Enter button Java

Tags: java

Существует ли в Java регулярное выражение нажатие клавиши Enter как в python /r?
Enter нужно отправить в консоль ssh, после выполнения команды.

Comment: Есть знак переноса строки. Выражения нажатия клавиши - не существует как понятия

Answer (score 1):

Вообще перенос строки обозначается по-разному для разных ОС, например, для Windows - `\r\n`.

Если вам нужно сделать перенос на след. строку внутри `String`, то можете просто использовать `\n` внутри строки.

Если вы хотите заменить все переносы строки на что-то другое, а ваш код должен поддерживать несколько ОС, то используйте `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, он вернет вам нужный знак переноса.

Comment: Выражение \r\n - это тоже строка. Просто было нужно понятно, есть ли в java enter как в python \r.

Answer (score 0):

Выражения нажатия клавиши Enter не существует в Джава!